# Rails add divide calculation to existing query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a query in which I pull all users who have invested in the portfolio, like below:

```
class PortfolioShareholdersQuery
  def initialize(portfolio)
    @portfolio = portfolio
  end

  def call
    User.joins(:cash_transactions)
        .where(cash_transactions: { to_wallet: portfolio.wallet })
        .select('users.*, SUM(cash_transactions.shares_number) as total_shares_number')
        .group('users.id')
  end

  attr_reader :portfolio
end
```

Is it possible to add inside of above query a line that will do the division of two numbers as below?

```
(user.total_shares_number / portfolio.portfolio_setup_infos.last.total_shares_sold)

# total_shares_number comes from first select
# portfolio_setup_infos is a has_many relation to portfolio
```

[Edit]

```
#models association
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one  :wallet, as: :walletable
  has_many :cash_transactions, through: :wallet
end

class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  has_one  :wallet, as: :walletable
end

class Wallet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :walletable, polymorphic: true

  has_many   :cash_transactions
end

class CashTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :wallet
  belongs_to :to_wallet, class_name: 'Wallet', optional: true
end
```

[Edit 2]

```
> divisor = portfolio.portfolio_setup_infos.last.total_shares_sold
  PortfolioSetupInfo Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "portfolio_setup_infos".* FROM "portfolio_setup_infos" WHERE "portfolio_setup_infos"."portfolio_id" = $1 ORDER BY "portfolio_setup_infos"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["portfolio_id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => 263

> shareholders = User.joins(:cash_transactions).where(cash_transactions: { to_wallet: portfolio.wallet }).select("users.*, SUM(cash_transactions.shares_number) as total_shares_number, (total_shares_number/#{divisor}").group('users.id')
  Wallet Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "wallets".* FROM "wallets" INNER JOIN "spv_setups" ON "wallets"."walletable_id" = "spv_setups"."id" WHERE "spv_setups"."portfolio_id" = $1 AND "wallets"."walletable_type" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["portfolio_id", 6], ["walletable_type", "SpvSetup"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (3.3ms)  SELECT users.*, SUM(cash_transactions.shares_number) as total_shares_number, (total_shares_number/263 FROM "users" INNER JOIN "wallets" ON "wallets"."walletable_type" = $1 AND "wallets"."walletable_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "cash_transactions" ON "cash_transactions"."wallet_id" = "wallets"."id" WHERE "cash_transactions"."to_wallet_id" = $2 GROUP BY "users"."id" /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT $3  [["walletable_type", "User"], ["to_wallet_id", 8], ["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM")
LINE 1: ... as total_shares_number, (total_shares_number/263 FROM "user...
                                                         ^
```

Comment: what's the relationship between User and Portfolio models?

Comment: @LesNightingill these two models don't have a defined relationship with each other. Question updated to show relations.

Comment: The denominator of your desired calculation is derived from an instance (portfolio) of  Portfolio. What are the conditions that specify which instance of Portfolio to use in this calculation?

Comment: portfolio is passed in a class call - `PortfolioShareholdersQuery.new(portfolio).call`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rb
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  def divisor
    portfolio_setup_infos.last.total_shares_sold
  end
end

class PortfolioShareholdersQuery
  def initialize(portfolio)
    @portfolio = portfolio
    @divisor = portfolio.divisor.to_f
  end

  def call
    select =<<-SEL.squish
                 users.*,
                 SUM(cash_transactions.shares_number) as total_shares_number,
                 (SUM(cash_transactions.shares_number)/#{divisor}) as ratio
              SEL

    User.joins(:cash_transactions)
        .where(cash_transactions: { to_wallet: portfolio.wallet })
        .select(select)
        .group('users.id')
  end

  attr_reader :portfolio, :divisor
end
```

Comment: I'm getting `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM")
LINE 1: ... as total_shares_number, (total_shares_number/263 FROM "user...`

Comment: I've added an alias, that might be the problem. What db are you using? Postgres? MySQL? If it still fails, pls show us the whole sql query and the error msg.

Comment: I'm using Postgres. I tested it in the console and well, there's not much more of an error line there - I've updated the question.

Comment: you should be able to see the actual sql, either in the console when you call the query, or else by appending `.to_sql` and then the `#call` method will return the sql query. What are you getting?

Comment: I believe that my last edit of my question (I posted an error there) answers your question

Comment: I can see a missing parenthesis after `/263` it's copied from the error in my response... I'll fix it.

Comment: Now I've `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "total_shares_number" does not exist)`

Comment: Ah OK, turns out you can't use an alias in the select clause. Do you need the intermediate `total_shares_number` value, or do you just need the value divided by the divisor?

Comment: I need them both

Comment: The `divisor` should be `.to_f` to avoid 0 as a result

Comment: Yes, but the result of `ratio` is always 0 if the divisor is not float

Comment: Great, I've edited my answer. Kindly designate my answer as "accepted".